# WordPress multiple revisions saved every minute

Tags: wordpress, autosave, revisions

When my client logs into WP, his system is somehow firing updates/revisions automatically (not  autosave) -- sometimes every minute; sometimes every other minute. Here is the revision log on one of the pages:

[Revision Log http://www.alliantstudios.net/clients/IAI/iai_revisionLog_1-16-13.png](http://www.alliantstudios.net/clients/IAI/iai_revisionLog_1-16-13.png)

Any idea what might be triggering this. He reports that on his end, the system times out when he tries to make an edit. I know that his company internet access has some security systems. Would that affect this? I've not seen this behavior before.

Any help on where to point me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No plugin updates? Or WP? Maybe some plugin went rogue with the hook `save_post`... Do a full [troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list).

Answer (score 0):

You could [Disable Post Revisions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Post_Revisions)

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );
```